# How to connect to Azure Container Instance running Server Core

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances

I create a new Container Instance. I use `microsoft/windowsservercore` as its docker image. Everything goes ok, without error.

But then, I cannot connect to it. I need to be able to connect to it so I can enable Remote PS. Container exec does not work.

```
az container exec --resource-group mydocker --name servercorecontainerinstance --exec-command "cmd.exe"
Exec to container failed
```

Instead, if I use `microsoft/iis:nanoserver` docker image with the instance then, I am able to connect to it.

```
 az container exec --resource-group docker --name winci --exec-command "cmd.exe"
[2J[H[1H[37;40m[K[2H[K[3H[K[4H[K[5H[K[6H[K[7H[K[8H[K[9H[K[10H[K[11H[K[12H[K[13H[K[14H[K[15H[K[16H[K[17H[K[18H[K[19H[K[20H[K[1;1HMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>
```

Some garbage chars show up everything else is ok.

How can I make this work with default server  `microsoft/windowsservercore`. Or is it the wrong image for server core to try out?

Moreover, why is it so hard to find documentation on running Server Core on Azure Container Instance?

Answer (score 0):

For the images about `microsoft/windowsservercore` and `microsoft/iis:nanoserver`, the former is a Microsoft native image, but the latter is installed IIS in the Microsoft image microsoft/nanoserver.

I have a try in Azure Container Instance with both images: `microsoft/windowsservercore` and `microsoft/nanoserver`. I both cannot connect to the container instance from these images. If I create the container instance from the image `microsoft/iis:windowsservercore`, I also can connect to it with the command `az container exec --resource-group mydocker --name servercorecontainerinstance --exec-command "cmd.exe"`.

So, I think if you want connect to the container from image `microsoft/windowsservercore`, you should install something in it. Just like the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/blob/master/windowsservercore-1709/Dockerfile) for IIS image from the Microsoft native image windowsserver.

Related to the difference about image windowsserver and nanoserver, you can read the document [Nano Server vs. Windows Server Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/system-requirements#nano-server-vs-windows-server-core).